# How to not show the popup again when user revisit my site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-5

I create auto popup in my website, but i have not show the auto popup again when user revisit my site?

My framwork is: `Laravel 5.2`

HTML:

```
<div id="popup_this">
  <span class="button b-close">
    <span>X</span>
  </span>
  <h3>A nice ad goes here!</h3>
  <p>Nulla at nunc posuere, dictum sem sed, tristique mi.</p>
</div>
```

jQuery bPopup plugin:

```
<script src="/path/to/jquery.bpopup.min.js"></script>
```

Script:

```
<script>
   $( document ).ready(function() {
      $('#popup_this').bPopup();
   });
</script>
```

Comment: You either store a value in a cookie, local storage or equivalent, or in a DB somewhere, and check against it.

Comment: @DaveNewton , Tank you so much, Please Elaborate on that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using [JS Cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) to set the cookie once the user has seen the pop-up.

Also, you dont need a plugin to perform the pop-up. Just use Jquery and add a class then style everything in css.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this with a simple localStorage.

You can read more about Storages in the browser here: [Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if(!localStorage.getItem('visited')){
    localStorage.setItem('visited',true);
    $('#popup_this').bPopup();}
});
```

Comment: Tahnk you so much